# Не запускается PySide

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside

Python 3.7.7 
при запуске вылезает это понять не могу в чем проблема и python другой(другие версий) ставил, библиотеку PyQt5  устанавливал

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сделайте скриншот вкладки "Проекты" для текущего проекта

Comment: @AlexanderChernin я не смогу сделать скрин вкладки так как сама программа не запускается, это не проект, это сама прога

Comment: Вы запускаете QtDesigner попробуйте запустить QtCreator

Comment: @AlexanderChernin У меня его нет

Comment: Могу только посоветовать все снести и установить заново отсюда https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer?hsCtaTracking=99d9dd4f-5681-48d2-b096-470725510d34%7C074ddad0-fdef-4e53-8aa8-5e8a876d6ab4 и не забудьте про совместимость разрядности python и qt

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Спасибо сейчас буду пробовать